# Local optimality of non-convex quadratic minimization with linear constraints

Tags: optimization, polyhedra, quadratic-programming, karush-kuhn-tucker

We are interested in minimizing a quadratic function, which is not convex. The feasible set is a polyhedron. We know that the global minimum is at a vertex when the function is concave.

Also, there is a paper which says for this type of problem "KKT conditions are necessary for global optimality", which I will cite asap.

My questions are:

1. is a KKT point local minimum, or local extremum?
2. under what case all the vertices are local minimum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there is more known about this specific problem than you say, you can not conclude that the global minimum is at a vertex.  If the feasible set is bounded and the objective function is concave, you can conclude that the global minimum is at a vertex. But you  can not reach that conclusion knowing only that the objective function is non-convex, because it could be indefinite (i.e., neither convex nor concave).

KKT conditions are necessary for global optimality, but they are not sufficient. If the Hessian of the objective function is indefinite, a point satisfying the KKT conditions could be any of 
1) global minimum
2) local minimum, which is not global minimum
3) saddle point
4) global maximum
5) local maximum, which is not global maximum

If the Hessian of the objective function is positive semidefinite, there are no saddle points, and every local minimum is a global minimum.  If the Hessian of the objective function is negative semidefinite, there are no saddle points, and every local maximum is a global maximum.

A point satisfying the KKT conditions (actually, you presumably mean the first order KKT conditions, can be determined to be a local minimum, saddle point, or local maximum, according to the 2nd order conditions. Specifically, a point satisfying the 1st order KKT conditions is a {local minimum, saddle point, local maximum} if the Hessian of the objective function projected into the null space of the Jacobian of active constraints (i.e., equality constraints and those inequalities which hold with equality at that point) is respectively {positive semidefinite, indefinite, negative semidefinite}.  Note that the Jacobian (matrix), is as defined at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant#Jacobian_matrix .

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Actually, I am interested in the case where  I minimize a concave quadratic function. So, I assume in this case the global optimum is at a vertex. 

Now the question is, in this case, how can we certify that a given vertex is \textbf{local minimum}? As I understand from your answer, I need to check the second order conditions. Is there an easier way to do since the function is concave in this case?

Comment: I should've stated "If the feasible set is bounded and objective function is concave, you can conclude that **three is a** global minimum at a vertex" I.e there'll be a global minimum at a vertex, but it 's possible that there are other global minima not at vertices. Minimizing a concave function on a bounded convex region, as here, is difficult- tough luck!!  One way to guarantee you've found the global minimum, presuming you can enumerate all vertices, is to evaluate objective function at all vertices and pick the best. Global QP solvers, sort of do this, but can cut off parts of the search.

Comment: A non-convex QP can be solved to global optimality by use of a global QP solver, such as CPLEX with optimalitytarget = 3, or a general purpose (rigorous) global nonlinear optimization solver, such as BARON. However, depending on the size and difficulty of the problem, it can take a long time, and large amount of memory, in the worst case until after the sun has died, which might interrupt the computation.On the other hand, it may be that you solve your problems of interest very quickly.

Comment: Thank you for these great comments. Rather than computing the global minimum, I am interested in returning whether a given vertex is a local minimum or not. In the concave case, can you think of any method for this purpose?

Comment: This question was answered in the last paragraph of my answer. Specifically, for  a QP, which is what you have, a point (whether or not it is a vertex  is a local minimum if and only if both the 1st order KKT condition is satisfied, and the second order condition for local minimum, as presented in the last  paragraph of my answer, is satisfied. If a point is a local minimum, it may or may not be the (a) global minimum.

Comment: If $H$ is the Hessian at the point being evaluated, and $Z$ a basis for the null space pf the Jacobian of active constraints at that point, then the Hessian projected into the the null space of the Jacobian of active constraints $=Z^THZ$. You then check to see whether $Z^THZ$ is positive senidefinite

Comment: Thank you! Ps: your last paragraph was for a general function, and in the comments, I wanted to specifically ask a concave one. But now it is clear!

Comment: As far as I know, \there is nothing more specific on this applying to concave vs. general non-convex You need to check 1st and 2nd order corditions at each point you are trying to assess for being a local minimum, and that is the same whether or not the point is a vertex.